# Detached JPA entities with associations in JSF backing beans

Tags: jsf, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jsf-2.2

In my current project, we use JSF 2.2, JPA 2 (Hibernate as persistence provider) and Spring Data JPA.

The situation is as follows, I tried to simplify as much as possible: we have an entity class `Car` with a bi-directional relation to `Extra`, with one `Car` referencing multiple `Extra` instances.

```
public class Car {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Extra> extras;

    // ...
}
```

`Extra` does only contain a single `String` property and the back-reference to `Car`.

In the backing bean for editing a single car and its extras, we have the situation that we want to keep the state of the bean in view scope (we have a custom `@ViewScope` Spring-based annotation for that, it has the same behavior as JEE's `@ViewScoped`).

The approach we have taken basically stores the `Car` instance directly in the backing bean. `CarRepository` is a Spring Data repository.

```
@Component
@ViewScope
public class CarEditView {

    @Getter @Setter
    private Integer id;

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Getter
    private Car car;

    public void load() {
        car = carRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public void save(){
        carRepository.save(car);
    }

    // ...
```

The `Car` instance is directly referenced and bound from certain JSF-related tags in the related *.xhtml file.

However, the `Car` instance gets detached after the first request. Now let's consider in the same view there is a way to add `Extra` instances to the `Car` instance. Maybe existing ones can be modified and deleted too.

What is the best practice JSF projects follow in cases where detached JPA entities with relationships to other entities are modified on the same page in-between multiple requests till they are explicitly saved?

(Please consider that `extras` is a lazy collection, so when this collection is not loaded and accessed, let's say, in the 2nd request, an exception will be thrown. However, keeping lists for new/modified/deleted `Extra` instances also feels a bit too much in terms of code complexity.)

Comment: Hiding from which developers? If you do all the merging in a 'service layer', the ui developers never need to know all this....

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for your comment. The question targets answers related to best practices in such scenarios. The last sentence might have led into another direction, so I removed it.

Comment: 'Best practice' questions are not really good questions on stackoverflow since they tend to be opinionated. But imo... 'hide it away in services'. Google a little on 'extended persistence' 'open session in view' and read related topics...

Comment: @Kukeltje Trust me, I've read through a lot of blog posts and I'm very familiar with the OSIV pattern (at least in Hibernate, but there is also an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` in Spring). However, related to the example from above, what would be the appraoch to take here? Where should I keep new/modified/deleted extras in the backing bean, is it really necessary to keep those `Extra` instances separetly in some helper lists or is this even already a use case for an extended persistence context?

Comment: Ok, then next time please state what you all found, why you think it is (or is  not) good. The current question is too open. Too little references (none) to related information etc... I personally just 'store/keep' all new items in a (helper) list and save/merge all when it actually needs saving. Sometimes already directly adding as a master/detail to another entity, sometimes not. All depending on the actual usecase,

Comment: @Kukeltje I see, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of cases are always difficult to manage. I suppose you're lazily loading the `Extra` collection for the case in which you list `Cars`, not to load all the cars with their extras. You've got many solutions:

1. Make the extra collection be eagerly loaded and limit the number of cars being loaded when the list is shown. That way you'll always have the extras available in your bean.
2. Implement a method to return the list of extras per car. This way you remove the relationship with the car entity itself and you treat each extra separatelly, for the view, just keep a collection with current extras (which can have an id or not) and other for the removed ones. When saving the edition, call the service methods you need to update the extras.

You could even abstract this from the view if you do this way in the service (considering you always save a car with its extras):

```
@Transactional
public Car save(Car car, Collection<Extra> assignedExtras){
    Car result = carRepo.save(car);
    List<Extra> savedExtras = extraRepo.findByCar(car);
    for (Extra extra : assignedExtras){
        extra.setCar(car);
        extraRepo.save(extra);
        savedExtras.remove(extra);
    }
    //Here, savedExtras contains only the extras you have removed, so let's remove them
    for (Extra extra : savedExtras){
        extraRepo.delete(extra);
    }
    return result;
}
```

3. Use the [Entity Graphs](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/), starting from JPA 2.1:

> Lazy loading was often an issue with JPA 2.0. You have to define at the entity if you want to use FetchType.LAZY (default) or FetchType.EAGER to load the relation and this mode is always used. FetchType.EAGER is only used if we want to always load the relation. FetchType.LAZY is used in almost all of the cases to get a well performing and scalable application.
>   But this is not without drawbacks. If you have to use an element of the relation, you need to make sure, that the relation gets initialized within the transaction that load the entity from the database. This can be done by using a specific query that reads the entity and the required relations from the database. But this will result in use case specific queries. Another option is to access the relation within your business code which will result in an additional query for each relation. Both approaches are far from perfect.
>
> JPA 2.1 entity graphs are a better solution for it. The definition of an entity graph is independent of the query and defines which attributes to fetch from the database. An entity graph can be used as a fetch or a load graph. If a fetch graph is used, only the attributes specified by the entity graph will be treated as FetchType.EAGER. All other attributes will be lazy. If a load graph is used, all attributes that are not specified by the entity graph will keep their default fetch type.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was afraid that the answer goes into that direction ;-) Thanks for mentioning the JPA 2.1 entity graphs, that's something I had overseen. We will investigate to find a way to maybe use eager fetching via Spring Data's @EntityGraph.